# Displaying Separate XML elements in a HTML table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I am trying to display separate xml elements in a html table. Below is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<channel id="sky_one" source="Sky" date="25/11/2014">
    <programme>
        <desc>Tony's motorcycle bursts into flames between his legs while town planner Liz is left in agony after her half-tonne horse bolts and lands on top of her. Also in HD</desc>
        <title>The Real A &amp; E</title>
        <end>0630</end>
        <start>0600</start>
    </programme>
    <programme>
        <desc>When Justin tries to detach a winch rope from a rock face during a charity event, a loose boulder falls on his pelvis. But with such rocky terrain, the Air Ambulance is unable to land. Also in HD</desc>
        <title>The Real A &amp; E</title>
        <end>0700</end>
        <start>0630</start>
    </programme>
    <programme>
        <desc>Temperatures rise as big boss Ken and legions of angry bakers take to the streets to protest against the 'Pasty Tax', before Greggs faces its biggest-ever crisis. (S1, ep 4) Also in HD</desc>
        <title>Greggs: More Than Meats The Pie</title>
        <end>0800</end>
        <start>0700</start>
    </programme>
    <programme>
        <subtitle>That's Lobstertainment</subtitle>
        <desc>Bender and Zoidberg travel to Hollywood in search of stardom. (S3, ep 8)</desc>
        <title>Futurama</title>
        <end>0830</end>
        <start>0800</start>
    </programme>
    <programme>
        <subtitle>The Birdbot Of Ice-Catraz</subtitle>
        <desc>Leela fights to save the lives of penguins after the Planet Express ship is involved in an oil spill on Pluto. (S3, ep 9)</desc>
        <title>Futurama</title>
        <end>0900</end>
        <start>0830</start>
    </programme>
```

I am using the jQuery and $ajax to retrieve the xml code. The jQuery is shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://scm.ulster.ac.uk/~B00533474/workspace/COM554/assignment_2/CR/sky_one.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        cache: false,
        success: parseXml2
    });
});

function parseXml2(Xml)
{
    $(Xml).find("programme").each(function() {
        $("#titl").append($(this).find("title").text());
    });
}
```

Then html as the output:

```
                <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>The Real A & E</td>
    <td>Greggs: More than meets the pie</td> 
    <td>Futurama</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The main problem is that the text which is displayed is all of the titles rather than just one title for one program in one area of the table. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you have a moment please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info). Your JavaScript is doing exactly what *you've asked it to do*. Please reduce your HTML to just what you wanted the final HTML to look like.

Comment: Thanks. The problem I am facing is that I do not know how to separate the xml elements into each section of the table?

Comment: ***Please reduce the HTML you posted to just what you wanted the final HTML to look like.***

Comment: Okay I have done this. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That still does not give us a picture of what you intended to do so we can make some suggestions. All we need is a **small sample** of html showing how the titles from the XML should look like when added to your page.

Comment: Is this what what you meant? I apologize for the delay. Could you help me out at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can put *unique* titles in a table:

```
function parseXml2(Xml) {
    var table = $('<table/>'),
        tbody = $('<tbody/>'),
        tr = $('<tr/>'),
        td = $('<td/>'),
        titles = [];
    $(Xml).find("programme").each(function() {
        var title = $(this).find("title").text();
        if( titles.indexOf( title ) === -1 ) {
            tr.append( td.clone().html( title ) );
            titles.push( title );
        }
    });
    $("#titl").append( table.html( tbody.html( tr ) ) );
}
```

```js
function parseXml2(Xml) {
        var table = $('<table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0"/>'),
            tbody = $('<tbody/>'),
            tr = $('<tr/>'),
            td = $('<td/>'),
            titles = [];
        //this part create the table cells
        $(Xml).find("programme").each(function() {
            var title = $(this).find("title").text();
            if( titles.indexOf( title ) === -1 ) {
                tbody.append( tr.clone().html( td.clone().html( title ) ) );
                titles.push( title );
            }
        });
        //this part creates the table and puts the table cells in it and appends the 
        //table to the #titl element
        $("#titl").append( table.html( tbody ) );
    }


//JUST FOR DEMO PURPOSES
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\
<channel id="sky_one" source="Sky" date="25/11/2014">\
    <programme>\
        <desc>Tony\'s motorcycle bursts into flames between his legs while town planner Liz is left in agony after her half-tonne horse bolts and lands on top of her. Also in HD</desc>\
        <title>The Real A &amp; E</title>\
        <end>0630</end>\
        <start>0600</start>\
    </programme>\
    <programme>\
        <desc>When Justin tries to detach a winch rope from a rock face during a charity event, a loose boulder falls on his pelvis. But with such rocky terrain, the Air Ambulance is unable to land. Also in HD</desc>\
        <title>The Real A &amp; E</title>\
        <end>0700</end>\
        <start>0630</start>\
    </programme>\
    <programme>\
        <desc>Temperatures rise as big boss Ken and legions of angry bakers take to the streets to protest against the \'Pasty Tax\', before Greggs faces its biggest-ever crisis. (S1, ep 4) Also in HD</desc>\
        <title>Greggs: More Than Meats The Pie</title>\
        <end>0800</end>\
        <start>0700</start>\
    </programme>\
    <programme>\
        <subtitle>That\'s Lobstertainment</subtitle>\
        <desc>Bender and Zoidberg travel to Hollywood in search of stardom. (S3, ep 8)</desc>\
        <title>Futurama</title>\
        <end>0830</end>\
        <start>0800</start>\
    </programme>\
    <programme>\
        <subtitle>The Birdbot Of Ice-Catraz</subtitle>\
        <desc>Leela fights to save the lives of penguins after the Planet Express ship is involved in an oil spill on Pluto. (S3, ep 9)</desc>\
        <title>Futurama</title>\
        <end>0900</end>\
        <start>0830</start>\
    </programme>\
        </channel>',
          xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
parseXml2( xmlDoc );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="titl"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. What HTML do I use to implement the table?

Comment: You're welcome. The table is implemented by the function; I have included a demo to help you visualize that.

Comment: Yes this is very helpful. One more question would be, how I can make the table vertical rather than horizontal?